# App Engine URL fetch callback

Tags: java, google-app-engine, asynchronous

I am relatively new to App Engine. I do not understand how to asynchronously make an HTTP request with Java. I would have thought that this was a very simple matter using Thread and Runnable. But it seems that App Engine does not permit their use.

```
public Hashtable someApiMethod(..) {
    SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(..);
    ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(entity).now();
    makeSomeHttpRequest(entity);
    return launchResponse;
  }
```

My question is this: how do I implement the method makeSomeHttpRequest(..) such that it returns without waiting for the URLFetchService.fetchAsync to return. I have tried the following without success:

```
protected void makeSomeHttpRequest(SomeEntity entity) {
        URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.example.com");
            Future future = fetcher.fetchAsync(url); 
            HTTPResponse response = (HTTPResponse) future.get();
            byte[] content = response.getContent();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bos.write(content);
            String responseString = new String(bos.toByteArray());
            int responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

            // Here I will do something with the responseCode and responseString
            if (responseCode == 200) entity.someValue = responseString;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle this
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle this
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // handle this
        }

    }
```

Really what I am trying to do is perform this HTTP request without forcing the method someApiMethod to wait for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

First. `Future` doesn't work this way. Method `.get` waits for result of Feature execution, so basically you're stopping current thread until other thread finishes its execution. You're making it synchronous, it doesn't make any sense. Usually you call `.get` much later, when all other work in current thread is finished

Second. Threads in Appengine are limited to current request, you have to complete all async processing during current request. So updating an entity in such way doesn't make much sense, it's still bounded to current request. I mean in your case `makeSomeHttpRequest(entity);` should work faster than `return launchResponse;`

What you really need is to send this data to *TaskQueue* and make processing of `SomeEntity entity` from there (but don't send entity itself, just send ID and load by id from queue task). Basically it's going to be a new request handler (servlet/controller/etc) that should load entity by id, execute `makeSomeHttpRequest` (synchronously) and return http status 200.

See TaskQueue docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/

You need Push Queue most likely: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push

Comment: Thank you Igor. I had looked at TaskQueues but it seemed like a lot of extra work to perform a simple asynchronous job. Also, the link you provided contains almost zero sample code. If you would like to provide sample code for a TaskQueue or a link to GitHub repo, I would be happy to review.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that you need to click on Push Queues - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push. I'll put it into answer

Comment: Thanks @Igor. I have implemented a Push Task Queue and it seems to work fine. I'd rather use a Thread and Runnable but it seems Google has its reasons for not allowing this.